# Always run cmd via ConEmu as administrator

Tags: cmd, admin, conemu

I'm using **ConEmu** and I want to **always** have my cmds run as **administrator**.

I've **changed** the settings that forces all my cmds to run through ConEmu, so typing 'cmd' in the Windows Run will open ConEmu (Settings -> Integration -> Default term -> Force ConEmu as default terminal)

I've **tried** changing the (Settings -> Startup -> Command line) to `cmd.exe -new_console:a` which works for shortcuts but doesn't change the default (running cmd from Run or opening a new tab inside ConEmu)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ConEmu **does not** change the command you run. That would be strange, if you run from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> the `cmd.exe` and get started in ConEmu `powershell.exe`, for example. Isn't it?

Same with elevation level. ConEmu starts console application at the level user requested. This is the only logical behavior.

Want elevated cmd? Set up elevated cmd task as startup task for ConEmu and run **ConEmu** instead of **cmd**.

Well, alternatively, you may run from <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `cmd -new_console:a` or just call "run cmd as Administrator" to let ConEmu know what do **you** want exactly.

Answer (score 30):

For me it works to change the specified named Tasks in Settings->Startup  to {Shells::cmd (Admin)}

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? What's the specified named Tasks and how to change it as exposed in the answer?

Comment: I think the specified named tasks is a field in the Settings->Startup to.
Change it to  {Shells::cmd (Admin)}. At the moment my pc doesn't work anymore and I cant't look in my settings. I will get a new one, but I think I don't want to use ConEmu anymore. Sorry. If I have time I try to reproduce it.

Comment: downvoted the other answer because this actually works!

Answer (score 6):

To elaborate on @Mike answer above , In the `Settings` window go to `Startup` menu item in the left pane . Now , in the main window there is a `Specified named task` drop down , select the admin option you want - for me it's `{cmd::Cmder as Admin}` . Click `Save settings` and now Cmder will open as admin every time .

Comment: I think that this drop down does not exist anymore, or a screenshot would help

Comment: It does, you just have to click the Startup menu itself and not one of its submenus.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on `ConEmu (x64)` icon. Select `Properties` > `Compatibility` Tab > Check `Run this program as administrator`

I have check it on windows 10.

[image: Run this program as administrator]

Comment: Thanks, it did the job

Answer (score 0):

on win11, it worked for me to go into the settings in conEmu, startup>Tasks, select your previously created predefined task, i called mine Ubuntu::Bash, and the in the commands parameter box: %windir%\system32\bash.exe ~ -cur_console:p  <<----this is what i had,
i added another line with an asterisk.  "*"

new commands parameter arguments:
%windir%\system32\bash.exe ~ -cur_console:p
[CONEMU settings screengrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fCgx.png)

*

worked great.

Comment: >> after looking at the way the site parsed my response, i think I should note, that the new commands parameter box should have two lines.  One with whatever it had before, and another with just an asterisk